# Augmented Reality in Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, app-store, augmented-reality, vuforia, google-play

I am making a augmented reality games and i used the vuforia sdk.

Here is my problem:

Can I use the augmented reality of vuforia and upload it in App Store and playstore?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, but appears to (maybe?) be about licensing issues?

Comment: do you have any idea about licensing in augmented reality of vuforia?.. Can I upload my game in App Store and Play store that uses the augmented reality of vuforia?

Comment: No, I don't. I just know that's completely off-topic here. Why not read the license agreement?

Answer (score 2):

The vuforia developer website has a section on publishing applications for both the app store and google play:
https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/publish-vuforia

You should carefully read and conform to the legal considerations and logo guidelines (see subsections). If you are still not sure about some specific elements for publishing your app, there is also an active forum where you can ask more precise questions:
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum

You can see some of example of published apps with Vuforia here:
https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/best-breed-examples

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is possible because with unity you can publish to Android, iOS, uwp.......If you want to publish to iOS make sure you are using Mac with XCode and in Unity->Player settings ->Other settings you will be required to add a message that user will see requesting the permission to use his device camera.